# Shopify API returning

Tags: python, xml, django, shopify

Oddly enough, this problem is intermittent, the last time it arose it persisted for a couple of days and then for some reason stopped happening, today while having shopify investigate another issue my inventory update script stopped working with this same ole error. The offending line appears to be

```
variant = Variant.objects.get(sku=sku)
```

The sku variable is being passed successfully. I would like to stress that this script is unmodified between when it worked for months except for 4 times in that period with this error and today. Obviously the url is malformed, but why is this happening?

--Traceback---

```
Internal Server Error: /inventory/process/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/projectname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/projectname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/projects/projectname/reponame/apps/shopified/views.py", line 103, in process
    update(sku, quantity)
  File "/home/username/projects/projectname/reponame/apps/shopified/inventory.py", line 72, in update
    inventory_quantity=quantity)).save()
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/projectname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 775, in save
    data=self.to_xml())
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/projectname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py", line 351, in put
    return self._open('PUT', path, headers=headers, data=data)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/projectname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shopify/base.py", line 19, in _open
    self.response = super(ShopifyConnection, self)._open(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/projectname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py", line 287, in _open
    http_response = self._handle_error(err)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/projectname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py", line 407, in _handle_error
    raise ResourceNotFound(err)
ResourceNotFound: Not Found: https://shop-name.myshopify.com/admin//variants/288274264.xml
```

Comment: Can you link the ResourceNotFound exceptions for each of the errors? I ask because this one has a potentially bad URL with two slashes after admin.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "link" the ResourcesNotFound exception, this is the only error I get. Also, I am pretty sure the URL is malformed, isn't that the cause of the exception to begin with?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api?

Comment: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api/blob/master/shopify/resources.py#L113 shows that it's appending a slash when not using the product scope but not when it is. And looking at the pyactiveresource code, https://github.com/ekarulf/pyactiveresource/blob/master/src/activeresource.py, it looks like it includes this slash..